# Increase performance in multi-select/hover state

Tags: reactjs, multi-select

I'm building a React grid application that uses windowing/virtualization, but I'm having issues with state updates that show obvious signs of lag behind interactions.

I'm trying to mimic Google Photo's multi-select feature where you are able to select a photo, hold down `Shift` key and move your mouse to preselect the highlighted photos. I'm having trouble building this "preselection" feature without lag.

I have a `onMouseEnter` event on each cell, storing the highlighted cells in state, the current row index with ref. I'm also wrapping the event in `debounce` with 100ms delay.

Comment: Can you show any code?

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, the icon effect should be achieved via CSS. I.e. it is always rendered and you just use CSS `:hover` to show it.

Likely, the perf problem is really only superficial -- with the icon visibility fixed, you are less likely to see any other real usability issues.

Arguably though you should not store the cells in state. After the CSS change, you wont need to conditionally render any more so there will be no need to use state. Those can be stored in refs and referenced further down the line. Refs are much much faster as they don't trigger a re-render.

Comment: The css :hover only works on the specific element that’s hovered, right? I’m having to calculate the nearest selected element on the row, and preselect that entire range. 

I’ve tried converting my state to a ref, but that caused the cells to not rerender when I move to another row.

Comment: Also to clarify, I’m only storing the cell index in state and not the entire cell component. The cell has a prop named isPreselected which is a Boolean based on whether or not that parent state includes this particular cell index.

Comment: Ah I had misunderstood your use case, apologies. Still I think this can be done with CSS much more easily. As for the refs not working -- yeh it wont cause a rerender updating the refs. However, when you need to perform some action on these cells in some handler, the value will be there in the ref. The idea is basically you wont need the rerenders if you solve the icon visibility issue with CSS. This tends to be a far more performant approach.

Comment: As for how -- it looks like it needs to show the icon for everything on the row up to and including the column the user is hovering over. This should be doable. You would apply CSS hover rules to the table *row*, which would then use a nested selector to display the icons for all cells in that row. Obviously this still isnt quite right. So you would also need some complex sibling selectors. See here for an example https://codepen.io/giana/pen/dWJzMK/. Ignore comment about msedge because thats talking about old pre-chromium ms edge.

Comment: The other angle you can look at is analysing using react developer tool profiling why exactly the rerenders are expensive in the first place and to either make them cheaper or use component memoization to reduce the amount of rerendering.

Comment: One final thing, yeh my wording was wrong what I meant was "Arguably though you should not store the selected cell indices in state. "